# How to convert 32 bit VBA code into 64 bit VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to run a macro code but since I'm using a 64 bit Excel 2016 this code is not working. Please help me how to fix this.

```
Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "User32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Private Declare Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" _
(ByVal lpsz As Long, ByRef lpiid As GUID) As Long

Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal dwId As Long, ByRef riid As GUID, _
ByRef ppvObject As Object) As Long
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/64-bit-visual-basic-for-applications-overview

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These should work on 64 bit Excel

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
  (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
  ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function IIDFromString Lib "ole32" _
  (ByVal lpsz As LongPtr, ByRef lpiid As GUID) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" _
  (ByVal Hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal dwId As Long, ByRef riid As GUID, _
  ByRef ppvObject As Object) As Long
```

If you need it to run on both you can use the following `#If VBA7`

```
#If VBA7 Then
    '64 bit declares here
#Else
    '32 bit declares here
#End If
```

A nice resource for PtrSafe Win32 API declares can be found here: [Win32API_PtrSafe.txt](http://www.cadsharp.com/docs/Win32API_PtrSafe.txt)

Comment: Thank you everyone.. This is very helpful and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

We need to do following two code changes:

1. Replace `Long` data type with `LongPtr`, at all places in the
   script
2. You need to change the private function declarations as
   below:

- OLD:

  ```
  Private Declare Function GetTimeZoneInformation Lib "kernel32" ( _
             lpTimeZoneInformation As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION) As Long
  ```
- NEW:

  ```
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTimeZoneInformation Lib "kernel32" ( _
         lpTimeZoneInformation As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION) As LongPtr
  ```

Comment: This worked for me, Win 11 MS 365

Comment: `Replace Long data type with LongPtr` - that is [absolutely wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63801528/11683). In particular, it is wrong for `GetTimeZoneInformation` that [returns a `Long`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-gettimezoneinformation) and not a `LongPtr`.