# Access vba code is illegal on access 2019

Tags: vba, ms-access, 32bit-64bit

As continuous to this question: [How to convert 32 bit VBA code into 64 bit VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557610/how-to-convert-32-bit-vba-code-into-64-bit-vba-code), I wrote the following vba access code:

```
#If VBA7 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "GetOpenFileNameA" (pOpenfilename As OPENFILENAME) As Long 
#Else
        'The folowing line is ilegal in Access 2019:
        Private Declare Function GetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "GetOpenFileNameA" (pOpenfilename As OPENFILENAME) As Long 
#End If
```

This code runs fine on Access 2013 but fails on Access 2019. The Else case is illegal on 2019.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong.

*VBA7* is *True* for Access 2007 and later, so the *Else* part will never run in a newer Access.

You will need Access 2003 or earlier to check out the *Else* part.