# How to run this VBA code in both Excel 32 bit and 64 bit

Tags: excel, vba

I have listview in my userform. Below code prevent user from changing column width of my listview. I have found this code online. I want to run this code in both 32 and 64bit excel. But i dont know how to rewrite the code so that the code can run in both 32 & 64 bit excel.

Here is my code.

```
    Option Explicit
    Option Base 0
    '''source code = https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?145805-Preventing-certain-Listview-columns-from-sizing&p=1710794&viewfull=1#post1710794
    ' GetWindowsLong Constants
    Private Const GWL_WNDPROC = (-4)
    
    ' Windows Message Constants
    Private Const WM_NOTIFY = &H4E
    Private Const WM_DESTROY = &H2
    
    ' Column Header Notification Meassage Constants
    Private Const HDN_FIRST = -300&
    Private Const HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKA = (HDN_FIRST - 5)
    Private Const HDN_BEGINTRACK = (HDN_FIRST - 6)
    
    ' Column Header Item Info Message Constants
    Private Const HDI_WIDTH = &H1
    
    ' Notify Message Header Type
    Private Type NMHDR
       hWndFrom As Long
       idFrom As Long
       code As Long
    End Type
    
    ' Notify Message Header for Listview
    Private Type NMHEADER
         hdr As NMHDR
         iItem As Long
         iButton As Long
         lPtrHDItem As Long ' HDITEM FAR* pItem
    End Type
    
    ' Header Item Type
    Private Type HDITEM
        mask As Long
        cxy As Long
        pszText As Long
        hbm As Long
        cchTextMax As Long
        fmt As Long
        lParam As Long
        iImage As Long
        iOrder As Long
    End Type
    
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As LongPtr, ByVal dwNewlong As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias "CallWindowProcA" (ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal Msg As LongPtr, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
    
    Private mlPrevWndProc As LongPtr, ColumnsBits As Long
    
    Private Function WindowProc(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
        Dim tNMH As NMHDR
        Dim tNMHEADER As NMHEADER
        Dim tITEM As HDITEM
        
        Select Case Msg
        Case WM_NOTIFY
            ' Copy the Notify Message Header to a Header Structure
            CopyMemory tNMH, ByVal lParam, Len(tNMH)
    
            Select Case tNMH.code
            Case HDN_DIVIDERDBLCLICKA
                ' If the user is trying to DOUBLECLICK a Column Header
                ' Extract Information about the Header being Sized
                CopyMemory tNMHEADER, ByVal lParam, Len(tNMHEADER)
    
                ' Don't allow Columns to be Sized.
                If (ColumnsBits And (2 ^ tNMHEADER.iItem)) = (2 ^ tNMHEADER.iItem) Then
                    WindowProc = 1
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Case HDN_BEGINTRACK
                ' If the user is trying to Size a Column Header
                ' Extract Information about the Header being Sized
                CopyMemory tNMHEADER, ByVal lParam, Len(tNMHEADER)
    
                ' Don't allow Columns to be Sized.
                If (ColumnsBits And (2 ^ tNMHEADER.iItem)) = (2 ^ tNMHEADER.iItem) Then
                    WindowProc = 1
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End Select
    
        Case WM_DESTROY
            ' Remove Subclassing when Listview is Destroyed (Form unloaded)
            WindowProc = CallWindowProc(mlPrevWndProc, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam)
            Call SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, mlPrevWndProc)
            Exit Function
        End Select
    
        ' Call Default Window Handler
        WindowProc = CallWindowProc(mlPrevWndProc, hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam)
    End Function
    
    Public Sub SubClassHwnd(ByVal hWnd As Long, ParamArray ColumnsNums())
        Dim t As Integer
        ColumnsBits = 0
        For t = 0 To UBound(ColumnsNums)
          ColumnsBits = ColumnsBits + (2 ^ (ColumnsNums(t) - 1))
        Next t
        mlPrevWndProc = SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, AddressOf WindowProc)
    End Sub
```

Can anyone help me to rewrite the code to run in both 32 and 64bit pc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What research did you do to fix the problem?

Comment: i have searched over net to change private declaration but have found nothing.

Comment: Really? Thought it is pretty easy to find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557610/how-to-convert-32-bit-vba-code-into-64-bit-vba-code

Comment: oh sorry my mistake. Ok thank you i will try this and let you know my code is  working or not. thank you for your help

Comment: i have tried but it saying type mismatch in last line        mlPrevWndProc = SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, AddressOf WindowProc)

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the revised code you're using?

Comment: ok i have changed "Private mlPrevWndProc As Long" to "Private mlPrevWndProc As LongPtr" the code is running but not working. I am changing my code with revised code.

Comment: I have updated my question with revised code