# Change focus from Outlook to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, focus

I have Outlook VBA code that gets specific text inside 'subject' mail, then opens and searches an Excel workbook for that text and if the text exists, shows a userform.

How do I set the focus from Outlook to Excel? The userform stays hidden and only shows when I click on the Excel window to activate it.

```vb
Sub abrirexecel()
    Dim ExApp As Excel.Application, planilha As String
    On Error Resume Next
    planilha = "'C:\Users\Dyme\" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "CodesSearch.xlsm'!funcaof12" 

    'funcaof12 is the macro name that opens userform

    Set ExApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Not ExApp Is Nothing Then
        ExApp.Run planilha
    End If
End Sub
```

Does anyone may give a help?

Comment: [`AppActivate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/appactivate-statement) maybe.

Comment: @BigBen, I have tried, but didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an Excel userform to open on Top by adding in a calling function within the userform. If you call this from Outlook it will open the form on top without activating Excel currently (some work for the calling code is needed to properly close the excel session)

For Example:

> In The Userform code

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
     'check if we are using XL97 or not (hWndUF global variable)
    hWndUF = IIf(Val(Application.Version) < 9, FindWindow("ThunderXFrame", Me.Caption), FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", Me.Caption))
End Sub
```

> In the Excel Module

```
Private Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, _
    ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long

Private Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1, SWP_NOMOVE = &H2, HWND_TOPMOST = -1, GW_HWNDNEXT = 2
Private Const FLAGS As Long = SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE

Public hWndUF As Long

Public Function ShowUserForm()
    Dim uf As Object: Set uf = UserForm1
    uf.Show vbModeless
    If hWndUF <> 0 Then SetWindowPos hWndUF, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, FLAGS
End Function
```

> Then in the Outlook module (this is dirty code and needs better object control; may look at later)

```
Sub ShowExcelUserForm()
    ' Requires reference: Microsoft Excel x.0 Data Objects library
    Dim ExApp As Excel.Application: Set ExApp = New Excel.Application 'Set ExApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Not ExApp Is Nothing Then
        ExApp.Run "'C:\Users\snapier\Desktop\Stack Overflow 2019.xlsm'!ShowUserForm"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Tragamor, but, sorry for the noobiest question: When i put this statement on vba editor, it turns RED. Do I need to activate some referencies? `Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long`

Comment: You may be running windows 64 bit in which case you will need to alter the calling function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557610/how-to-convert-32-bit-vba-code-into-64-bit-vba-code