# VBA Codes 32bit to 64bit

Tags: vba

I found some VBA codes that I need, but I can't use these codes because they are 32 bit. How can I convert them to 64bit?

```
Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SendMessageStr Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SendMessageAny Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndParent As Long, ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, lpdwProcessId As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function VirtualAllocEx Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByVal lpAddress As Long, ByVal dwSize As Long, ByVal flAllocationType As Long, ByVal flProtect As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function VirtualFreeEx Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpAddress As Any, ByVal dwSize As Long, ByVal dwFreeType As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ReadProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpBaseAddress As Any, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nSize As Long, lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function WriteProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpBaseAddress As Any, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nSize As Long, lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Long) As Long
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557610/how-to-convert-32-bit-vba-code-into-64-bit-vba-code, theres a link in the reference that you can look into as well.

Comment: It would be great if someone could convert them for me. I do not understand much.

Comment: Search [here](https://www.cadsharp.com/docs/Win32API_PtrSafe.txt) for each function declaration. If not all of them are there, search on internet for these one. **There is no a rule able to work for any API Function**. The single one would be to add `PtrSafe`, but after that, according to the necessary parameters not all `Long` should be transformed in `LongPtr`. Each API function has its own conversion rule...

Comment: Also have a look to this tool: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/dennis/windowsapiviewer.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageStr Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageAny Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndParent As LongPtr, ByVal lpEnumFunc As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wCmd As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, lpdwProcessId As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function VirtualAllocEx Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As LongPtr, ByVal lpAddress As LongPtr, ByVal dwSize As Long, ByVal flAllocationType As Long, ByVal flProtect As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function VirtualFreeEx Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As LongPtr, lpAddress As Any, ByVal dwSize As Long, ByVal dwFreeType As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ReadProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As LongPtr, lpBaseAddress As Any, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nSize As LongPtr, lpNumberOfBytesWritten As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WriteProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As LongPtr, lpBaseAddress As Any, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nSize As LongPtr, lpNumberOfBytesWritten As LongPtr) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

The above will work on both x32 and x64. If you still need them to run in VB6 then use this:

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageStr Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageAny Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndParent As LongPtr, ByVal lpEnumFunc As LongPtr, ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wCmd As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, lpdwProcessId As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function VirtualAllocEx Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As LongPtr, ByVal lpAddress As LongPtr, ByVal dwSize As Long, ByVal flAllocationType As Long, ByVal flProtect As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function VirtualFreeEx Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As LongPtr, lpAddress As Any, ByVal dwSize As Long, ByVal dwFreeType As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ReadProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As LongPtr, lpBaseAddress As Any, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nSize As LongPtr, lpNumberOfBytesWritten As LongPtr) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function WriteProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As LongPtr, lpBaseAddress As Any, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nSize As LongPtr, lpNumberOfBytesWritten As LongPtr) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "user32" Alias "GetClassNameA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function SendMessageStr Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function SendMessageAny Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
    Private Declare Function EnumChildWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal hWndParent As Long, ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Integer) As Integer
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, lpdwProcessId As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function VirtualAllocEx Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByVal lpAddress As Long, ByVal dwSize As Long, ByVal flAllocationType As Long, ByVal flProtect As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function VirtualFreeEx Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpAddress As Any, ByVal dwSize As Long, ByVal dwFreeType As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function ReadProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpBaseAddress As Any, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nSize As Long, lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function WriteProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpBaseAddress As Any, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nSize As Long, lpNumberOfBytesWritten As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If
```