# How this macros can run on 64 and on 32 bit office

Tags: excel, vba

Hello can you somone tell me how make this macros to run on 32 bit and on 64 bit Office?

on 32 bit macros is run but on 64 bit it not and it is in red color. Thank you.

````
Public Declare Function CreatePopupMenu Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long`
Public Declare Function GetMenu Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function AppendMenu Lib "user32" Alias "AppendMenuA" (ByVal hMenu As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal wIDNewItem As Long, ByVal lpNewItem As String) As Long
Public Declare Function SetMenu Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hMenu As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function DestroyMenu Lib "user32" (ByVal hMenu As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias "CallWindowProcA" (ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As Long, ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long```
````

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557610/how-to-convert-32-bit-vba-code-into-64-bit-vba-code

Comment: Helpful, too with links & examples: [Declaring API functions in 64 bit Office](https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/apideclarations.asp)

Comment: I try it but: on 32 menus are ok, on 64 when click on menu it is happen nothing: I sent pasebin on userform and on macros:  [link](http://pastebin.com/m3gg51z2)
 [link](http://pastebin.com/nskw12r4)


Where I wrong?

Comment: What I change on this file to run it on 64 bit Office? He starts, but when I click on command in menus nothing happened. Please help me. Thank you! here is file:[link](https://liteshare.co/files/KM5LYW2)